# Problem to see data in ArcGIS Enterprise from a Query Layer

Tags: query-layer, arcgis-enterprise, dashboard

We have created a Query Layer in ArcGIS Pro. It connects to a SQL Server database asking for the result of a SQL Server User Defined Function (not a View). Its syntax is as shown below, where (parameter) indicates the number of previous days of the registers to obtain:

SELECT * FROM [*database name*][*admin*][*function name*] (*parameter*)

In ArcGIS Pro this query works perfectly and we can see the result. It includes a geometry field (XY points) as SHAPE and some other attributes of these coordinates. The result includes an index of unique numbers.

Later, we can load it as a Web Layer to ArcGIS Enterprise without any error during the uploading process. But when we try to create a Web Map and load this layer, the obtained table appears without any values in Map Viewer. In Map Viewer Classic it indicates there is an error accessing the data. No further information is provided by the ArcGIS software.

The final aim of this query is to be used in a Web Map for a Dashboard that will be periodically refreshed.

The database is included in the data stores and it gets validated correctly.

What may be the reason of this error? I don't know if maybe a query to a function is not permitted.

Comment: That database may be registered and accessible, but that doesn't mean the credentials that ArcGIS Server are using will work.  If the connection relies on OS Authentication, make sure the Windows account running ArcGIS Server has proper permissions on the database.

Comment: Server does validation to enforce standard SQL (and prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities), which would probably choke on this syntax. If you want to publish a service, it's probably best to do it with a view, not a function.